# URL code assistance please short code (Newbie Java programmer)

Tags: java, url, audio, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans and trying to make a Jbutton play this .wav file that I have located in the build/classes/shadow part of my project. I want the .Jar to build with the .wav file so I could download the .Jar file on another computer and press the button and the music will play. The music is not locating or starting I'm not sure which it is, also please be easy on the terminology I am very very new.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:File Clap = new File("sanic.WAV");
display.setText("cum on step it up!!!"); 
} 
 public static void startMusic() {
 {
try{
  URL url = Shadow.class.getClassLoader().getResource("sanic.wav");
  play(); // NetBeans says it cannot find the symbol for play.


}catch(Exception e){ 
    }                                       
    }                                        
 }
```

Comment: What happens when you compile the code? can you show the output in your question? Also where is the play() method in  your code? I see that it has been called but where is the actual method?

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry I don't know how to make a play() method.

Comment: Netbeans is gonna always throw an error then. If the play() method is called but not declared/made, how is the compiler supposed to know what play() method does?

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge, I'll look into how to create methods for commands. I'm using this code now It won't locate my .wav file and I don't know why.

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    }private Clip music;
//...
private void startSong(){
  try{
   AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("sanic.wav"));
   music = AudioSystem.getClip();
   music.open(stream);
   music.start();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
  music = null;

Comment: Where should I put the sanic.wav file so it can find it, pick it up, use it as a resource and stream it?

Comment: Have you considered putting the directory Path in when it references the sanic.wav file? For ex: `URL url = Shadow.class.getClassLoader().getResource("C:/sanic.wav");`

Comment: Yeah I just tried this AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Helen\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\finally\\build\\classes\\resource\\sanic.wav")); but no sound unfortunately. It says finally because I made a new project to try out the new code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in what part of your code are you using your URL... But I'd suggest you to use [AudioInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioInputStream.html)...

Regarding the problem finding the file... I had implemented something similar some time ago, while checking the code I have in my HDD, I found that this made it for me:

```
URL url = Shadow.class.getResource(myfile.wav);
```

But nowadays, I prefer working with this:

```
InputStream resourceAsStream = Shadow.class.getResourceAsStream(myfile.wav);
```

Hope it helps for what you need to do.

Regards and... happy coding :)

Comment: Hey thank you so much for responding! I erased what I had and put in that line of code but now I need to know what commands to use to start the music, I think this is done by making it a variable? I'm not sure.

Comment: private Clip music;
//...
private void startSong(){
  try{
   AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResource("sanic.wav"));
   music = AudioSystem.getClip();
   music.open(stream);
   music.start();
  }
  catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   music = null;
  }
 }  This could work, but I can't locate my .wav file!

Comment: Then you can try Media, since that component accepts uris that link to a file inside jar:
new Media(Shadow.class.getResource("/resources/sanic.wav").toURI().toString());

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got it working by removing private void startSong() I assumed it was interfering because of the private void part. I wasn't able to get the button to play the music, but I was able to get the music to start upon execution of the .Jar file. For some reason it skips the Jbutton's action listener.

Comment: Nice to know you get it working, way to go. All the best and happy coding :)